# Populating the '<input>' value based on the selected value of a dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display an `<input>` value base on a selected value of a dropdown list using jquery ajax.

This is the markup for my form -

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label">District</label>
    <div class="element">
        <select class="form-control" id="district">
            <?php echo $option; ?>
        </select>                               
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Province</label>
    <div class="element">
        <input type="text" class="form-control province" placeholder="Province" value="" disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

Just I need to display province input's value When selecting a district from above dropdown.

This is my ajax code -

```
$("#district").change(function(event) {
    var id = $("#district").val(); 
    //alert(data);

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
            url: "./includes/process_province.php",
            type: "post",
            data: id,
            success: function(){
                alert('Submitted successfully');
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

When I selecting a district from the dropdown its going to this alert `alert('Submitted successfully');`. But I am not sure how to display PHP processing value in my text field.

This is my `PHP` code from `proccess_province.php`

```
// Require the configuration file before any PHP code:
require('./configuration.inc.php');

// Need the database connection:
require('../'.MYDB);

if(isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $province_id = (int)$_POST['id'];

        // Select exsiting data for an user and display them in the form for modify 
    $prep_stmt = " SELECT province
                                 FROM province 
                                 WHERE province_id = ?";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        // Bind "$userId" to parameter.
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $province_id);  
        // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->execute();    
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($province);
        // Fetch all the records:
        $stmt->fetch();

        $db_province     = filter_var($province, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        //echo $province;

    } else {
        echo 'Database error';
    }   

    echo $db_province;
}
```

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: If the user never sets the input, you should use the newer `output` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you echo the value of the province in the ajax file, you need to set the value based on that response. Try this:

```
     $.ajax({
            url: "./includes/process_province.php",
            type: "post",
            data: id,
            success: function(data){
                $('#province').val(data);
                alert('Submitted successfully');
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
    });
```

And your markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Province</label>
    <div class="element">
        <input id="province" type="text" class="form-control province" placeholder="Province" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aditya, I tried it with your answer. But still its going to success alert massege but not populating <input> value.

Comment: Make sure you are getting the response value from the php file. In your browser console, check the ajax XHR response. If you are getting the name of the province correctly then it should work.

Comment: Yes I checked it with net tab in firebug. Then I can see POST vlaue is ok. But I can see nothing in HTML tab there..

Comment: That's wierd. Try removing `value=""` from the `<input>` and check. Also remove `disabled`

Comment: Yes I checked. But still no luck. Removed disabled also

Comment: I tried `process_province.php` running directly. Then I can see that script is working.

Comment: Adiya, Can I know is this line `if(isset($_POST['id'])) {` correct in my processing script?

Comment: When I check this processing script directly, I removed main if condition. ('if(isset($_POST['id'])) { }`). Then I could to see the script is working. If not the is nothing display.

Comment: Just I found the `id` from selected dropdown is not going to processing script properly. any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the value of input same as your select option value, you can change your success callback to this-

```
$.ajax({
        url: "./includes/process_province.php",
        type: "post",
        data: id,
        success: function(){
            $('.province').val(id);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
});
```

Or, if you are bothered about the ajax response and populate the value of input based on the ajax response, you can access the data being returned as follows-

```
$.ajax({
        url: "./includes/process_province.php",
        type: "post",
        data: id,
        success: function(data){
            // access data here and do something
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to php file -

```
$db_province = filter_var($province, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo json_encode($db_province);
```

at the end.

On the html page -

```
<input type="text" id="province" class="form-control province" placeholder="Province" value="" readonly>
```

then set the response to the field value -

```
success: function(response){
    $('#province').val(response)
    alert('Submitted successfully');
},
```

Comment: Its going to alert but not populating <input> value

Comment: Have you removed the disable attribute?

Comment: Are you getting any error or what is the response you are getting??

Comment: What is the response you are getting?

Comment: In jquery I changed `data: {id:id},` then I could get it to work.

Comment: That could matter as you are checking for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69878/discussion-between-user3733831-and-sgt).

Comment: Can we chat regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

In the the form change the code as,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Province</label>
    <div class="element">
        <input type="text" id="province" class="form-control province" placeholder="Province" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

In script section use,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#district").change(function(event) {
    var id = $("#district option:selected").val(); 

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
            url: "./includes/process_province.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {id : id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(){
                $('#province').val(data.province);
                alert('Submitted successfully');
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

In the proccess_province.php file, instead of

```
echo $db_province;
```

use,

```
echo json_encode(array('province' => $db_province));
```

Hope it helps.